# Is there a strategy in Dragon Quest Heroes Rocket Slime how to catch a goody bag?

Tags: nintendo-ds, dragon-quest-heroes

I need to know how to catch goody bags and where they appear most. Is there a strategy? Is there a place that they appear most often? If I could know, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

They appear in the desert at night.  Sometimes you need to wander around, and then you might bump into one.

Answer (score 1):

I found all mine in Backwoods, but I think I saw one in Tutinschliemen.  They don't appear during daytime, but they can appear during any other time.  Every time you enter any room, the monster spawn is random, so once you find one near a door or area transition, just keep walking back and forth until you get all the ones you need.